# Medical insurance for permanent resident parents Canada

Tags: canada, insurance, residency

I am a permanent resident of Canada. I am planning to sponsor my parents to come and live with me in Canada as permanent residents. Looking at this page, http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/sponsor/parents.asp it says that the sponsored parents should not seek social assistance. Does medical insurance in Canada qualify as social assistance? Does that I mean I can't get medical insurance for them after they come and settle here?

Comment: I assume that hit it means is that they shouldn't rely on government/taxpayer funded 'social assistance'. Private medical insurance you pay for out of your pocket should be fine.

Comment: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/newcomers/after-health.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Canada the term "social assistance" is a politer synonym for [welfare](http://canadianimmigrant.ca/featured/what-is-welfare), which are benefits provided based on need. Provincial health insurance is a benefit available to all residents whether they "need" it or not.  The rules for qualifying vary by province but it is generally available after 3 months of residence (in Ontario this is true if one is absent from the province no more than 30 days in the first 6 months); you may need to find private insurance to cover them until then if you don't want to gamble.